# Help with derivative of nested inverse functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inverse-function

Assume that $f$ is an arbitrary monotonically increasing on $[0,1]$.
I am trying to compute the following:

$\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(f(x)-1)$

Where $f^{-1}$ is the inverse function.

The current best line of work I have is using the chain rule and inverse function rules I get:

$f'(x) \cdot 1/f'[f^{-1}(f(x)-1)]$

However, this seems to just be creating an infinitely nested function. As such I am stuck.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: How about the chain rule?

Comment: You have the correct expression, and there is quite a bit of nesting going on, I find it easier to look at formatted like this...$$ \frac {f'(x) }{f'\left (f^{-1}(f(x)-1)\right )}$$

Comment: Yup, you have it right, and it's certainly not infinite nesting, it's merely three levels.